# shiny app - saving and loading

Tags: shiny-server, shiny

I have a shiny app
where I upload a csv file
and then render it in UI using renderdatatable.
Now, I take the uploaded file as a a dataframe annd save it to a rdata file.
If the user interacts with the application again 
I would like to load the csv file from the file system using renderdatatable.
To accomplish this I just use the load function and then call the dataframe.
I would like to know if there is a similar implementation on the same

Answer (score 0):

A few things unclear here are when you say user interacting with the application again, do you mean a reactive response like changing a value in a text box or dropdown and accordingly re-displaying the contents of your dataframe; or a completely new session where the user wants to retrieve the previously viewed data.
If it is about a reactive response, then once the csv is read, you could access it by calling it with the input object - input$file1 or reading the temp location where the uploaded file gets saved (eg tmpdir())